# Help me identify a blatant Star Wars clone

Tags: story-identification

Over lunch, I was conversing with some friends about a Sci-Fi movie I saw on TV many years ago (I believe it was in the late 80's, but I'm pretty sure the movie itself was older than this).

I recalled it as a hilariously-atrocious rip-off of Star Wars, complete with lightsabers (or "laser swords," as I think they were called in this movie). Of course, given the popularity of Star Wars at the time, I'm sure there were plenty of similar films churned out; fortunately, I remember a number of specific details about it that have made it stand out in my mind all these years:

- A main character looks alarmingly like David Hasselhoff
- The "Death Star" looked like a giant hand
- The movie's climax featured a shootout on space station with strange assault pods crashing through big windows (really!)
- It featured a heroine named Stella (or possibly Stellar, though this makes less sense)

While I found the movie hilarious, it was not intended as a comedy. It was simply one of those "so bad, it's good" situations.

Comment: Space balls? Doesn't sound quite right as I recall it, though.

Comment: Not *Space Balls* as I doubt that Mega Maid could be misremembered as a hand...

Comment: [Hardware Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_Wars)?

Comment: Use the schwartz!

Comment: I have updated the question to be clear that this movie was not _intended_ to be a comedy. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: If it *wasn't* SpaceBalls, it **SHOULD HAVE BEEN** SpaceBalls!! And may the schwartz be with you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Star Crash](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=star%20crash&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079946/&ei=t2EoT_jVKYSPigKJms21AQ&usg=AFQjCNH2hx34RTpMW-O6in9ognv6nyYa5Q)! And that *is* the Hoff.

Comment: That's it! I can't believe that's really the Hoff!